# Skipping specific directory using for loop in a Batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I am trying to process all the directory present in a given directory. However, i want to skip a particular set of directories and i know the names of these directory. Here's the pseudo code

```
for /D %%G in ("%ROOT_VAR%\mainDirectory\*") do (
if "%%G" == "%%ROOT_VAR%%\mainDirectory\dir_to_be_skipped" (
echo "Skipping dir_to_be_skipped"
)

continue processing other directory
```

How do i do that in batch script ? I just want to skip processing dir_to_be_skipped

Thank
Kelly

Comment: @Kelly, what's wrong with what you've got? It works for me..

Comment: You are **not** the first guy with this question, example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16819972/2098699).

Comment: @Blorgbeard,It doesn't skip dir_to_be_skipped,

Comment: @Blorgbeard It worked ! I had tried it before but didn't put the ) else ( in the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! Add an `else`:

```
for /D %%G in ("%ROOT_VAR%\mainDirectory\*") do (
    if "%%G" == "%%ROOT_VAR%%\mainDirectory\dir_to_be_skipped" (
        echo "Skipping dir_to_be_skipped"
    ) else (
        continue processing other directory
    )
)
```

Note that the `) else (` must all be on the same line.